# Computing the probability that at least four telephone lines are not in use.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A mail-order computer business has six telephone lines. Let $X$ denote the number of lines in use at a specified time. Suppose the pmf of $X$ is as given in the accompanying table:
 $p(0)=.10$, $p(1)=.15$, $p(2)=.2$, $p(3)=.25$, $p(4)=.2$, $p(5)=.06$, $p(6)=.04$

Calculate the probability of $\{\text{at least four lines are not in use}\}$.

I interpreted the problem as find $P(4 \leq X \leq 6)$ but I'm not getting the correct answer. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want $P(0 \le X\le 2)$. Remember it said **not** in use.

Comment: Yeah but why wouldn't we include 3? so that X is between and including 0 and 3?

Comment: @user23793: If there are six total lines and four of them are not in use, what's the maximum number that could be in use?

Comment: Sigh* thank you for that epiphany.

Answer (score 2):

To help you understand it, think of this
$$
P(0) = P(\text{ 6 lines not in use} )\\
P(1) = P(\text{ 5 Lines not in use })\\
P(2) = P(\text{ 4 Lines not in use })
$$
Then
$$
P(\text{ 6 Lines not in use })+P(\text{ 5 Lines not in use })+P(\text{ 4 Lines not in use })= \\
P(0)+P(1)+P(2)=0.1+0.15+0.2=0.45
$$